# _HAS_EXCEPTIONS=1 vs _HAS_EXCEPTIONS=0

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, command-line

Hi guys on Visual Studio Command Line, what is the difference between _HAS_EXCEPTIONS = 0 and =1. Might it be that _HAS_EXCEPTIONS is just a boolean and that is the value that it takes?
Also I have read that it is for exceptions that this flag is for setting up exceptions on STL so 1 and 0 would mean that exceptions are on or off, right?
Thank you
Carlos.

Comment: It is a *macro*.  Designed to still allow compiling 20 year old C++ code that was written before the language acquired exception support but non-standardized STL templates were getting in vogue.  Don't use it.