# std::terminate with disabled exceptions (MSVC implementation)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, terminate

Calling `std::terminate()` from code compiled with disabled exceptions, I noted that behavior differs for gcc and msvc. In first case program was aborted as I expected, whereas in second case nothing happened (the program continued execution).

As it turns out, msvc has dummy implementation for terminate function when _HAS_EXCEPTIONS macro is not set:

```
inline void __CRTDECL terminate() _NOEXCEPT
{   // handle exception termination
}
```

Visual Studio 2017, Version 15.7.2

cppreference says:

> std::terminate() may also be called directly from the program.

Doesn't this mean that abort/handler must be called anyway, not depending on exceptions ability?

Comment: While it is certainly a good idea not to make too many gratuitious changes in any not-C++ language to the base language, one cannot appeal to the C++ standard as it is not C++, only to common sense, which might not be as common as hoped for, or simply not ours.

Comment: I'm not sure how you are getting this behavior. If exceptions are disabled than std::terminate invokes `abort`. I don't see any kind of dummy implementation being actually called. [Probably related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20221715/has-exceptions-1-vs-has-exceptions-0)

Comment: _"The option _HAS_EXCEPTIONS=0 is undocumented, untested, and unsupported by Microsoft. ..."_: source https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2015/07/14/stl-fixes-in-vs-2015-part-2/

Comment: @RichardCritten, I think this comment should be the answer.

Comment: @VTT, do you have different implementation in the exception header? What version of Visual Studio do you have?

Comment: I've just disabled exceptions. Note that I did not mess with `_HAS_EXCEPTIONS`.

Comment: Re: "Doesn't this mean..." -- it means that you have to read the documentation for the compilers that you're dealing with. Turning off exceptions is not part of the C++ standard, so anything that the standard says is irrelevant when you do this.

Comment: It seems that _HAS_EXCEPTIONS=0 is only way to turn-off exceptions in STL. [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/553103/9027283)

Comment: @PeteBecker: Compiler specifics shouldn't be in conflict with the standard, do they?

Comment: @KernelPanic -- the C++ standard isn't a law. Compiler vendors don't **have to** follow it. There's commercial pressure to do so, but compilers have lots of non-conforming "features", like turning off exceptions.